# Show user's email when commenting rather than asking for input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I created a blog in which users can create comments under posts. Registered users, Admins and Guests will be able to post comments.

So in the _form.html.erb I wrote this:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
    <% if current_user || current_admin %>
      <% @comment.commenter = current_user.try(:email) || current_admin.try(:email) %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.input :commenter %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

However I get this error: undefined local variable or method `comment'.

When I try to change @comment.commenter to @post.comments I get the error: undefined method `each' for "example@person.com":String.

Is there a way set the commenter's name if its registered. Like in the controller maybe?

The controller code is:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comments_params)
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private
  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
  end
end
```

If you need any other information please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Post the controller code

Comment: added the controller file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

Controller:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(comments_params)
    if current_admin || current_user
      @comment.commenter = current_user.try(:email) || current_admin.try(:email)
      @comment.save
    end
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
```

View:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build], html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
    <% if current_admin || current_user %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
    <% else %>
    <%= f.input :commenter %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= simple_form_for(@comment),url: [@post,@comment], html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :commenter, value: comment_by_user %>
<%= f.input :body %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
```

Helper

`def comment_by_user` 
  `current_user.try(:email) || current_admin.try(:email) if current_user || current_admin`
`end`

Controller

`class CommentsController < ApplicationController`
  `before_filter :find_post`

`def new`
  `@comment = @post.comments.build`
 `end`
 `def create`
 `@comment = @post.comments.create(comments_params)`
  `redirect_to post_path(@post)`
`end`

`def destroy`
 `@comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])`
 `@comment.destroy`
`redirect_to post_path(@post)`
`end`

`private`

`def find_post`
  `@post = Post.find(params[:post_id])`
 `end`
`end`